# Cannot connect to local server using servername/instancename

Tags: sql-server

I have reached a point where I need to use Excel to pull information from a SQL Server instance that is running on the same machine.

As I will not be the only user to use Excel I need to use the MyComputer1234\MSSQLSERVER, 1433 details to connect however it cannot find the server?

Other users can connect to the above details and I can connect if I specify '.' or 'local'...why can't I connect to the named details?

Surface config allows local and remote connections using both TCP/IP and named pipes

EDIT: I have looked on the SQL Server Profiler and created a trace, when other colleagues connect I can see an entry on the log against their user IDs, I also see one when I log on using the local details. However when I try ServerName\InstanceName, PortNumber nothing shows, its as if the connection is not coming through?

Comment: Your slash is backwards on the SERVER\INSTANCE.  Most likely a simple typo, but would prevent it from working if that's what you're attempting to connect with :)

Comment: edited the question, thanks but that was my mistake when typing the question

Comment: Is it possible that your machine has been renamed at any point after SQL was installed on it?

Comment: I have run @@Servername and @@servicename against the server and they are still the same

Comment: Try with only SERVERNAME because your instance is on 1433 port (as default Sql Server port). The same, if you try with SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME (always without port).

Comment: @Chris Can you provide the connection string that your colleagues are using in Excel? Are you using the same file as they are from a network share or your own copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been addressed previously;

[Unable to connect to SQL server 2008 R2 via Instance name?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41114/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008-r2-via-instance-name)

Basically MSSQLServer is the default instance name, so by accident you have come across this scenario where you can only connect to the service by not specifying the instance name. Perhaps this is more stringent for local connections vs. remote connections.

Comment: I was able to connect to the server a few weeks ago using the full details, I don't understand why all of a sudden I cant?

Comment: Oh ok, I'd suggest adding that to your question as it's a key aspect. Following up on the default instance suggestion, what happens when you try to "MyComputer1234\"?

Comment: @Chris, what do you get back from the query SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') from your collegue's remote connections?

Comment: I get null as the option, it works just using MyComputer1234\ not sure what changed over the past few weeks but this solution will work for the team! Thanks

Comment: @Chris, perhaps you changed from SQL Server express to a fuller install of SQL Server where the default instance name is different. Glad it has worked out for you though.